Azure DevOps extention - Injecting logic to existing page - identifying the correct contribution
I want to create an extention to modify the Pull Request list page in DevOps. I have the extention working if I want to add a new menu option in the list undo "Repo" but not modifying the existing page.

I'm unable to find the correct extention points (contributions) to use to have my extention load when this page loads. The documentation is really unclear on how to identify these extension points.
What is the best way to move identify them? Has anyone else done something similar
Thanks
S

The "Pull requests" option is a built-in hub under the Azure Repos hub group (ms.vss-code-web.code-hub-group). You cannot change/customize the page layouts of the existing hub. You need to create a new hub for your custom page under the Azure Repos hub group.
For pull requests, we can develop extensions to do the following things:

Add custom tab pages on the page of opening pull requests.


Add custom option to actions menu on the page of opening pull requests.



For more information, you can see the documentation "Extensibility points".


That is such a shame you cannot performance some action when a specific page loads. It seems the DevOps extension API's are a little weak in terms of capability
